# Display product value in a button

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I have three buttons where I select a value and put in the button. Upon selecting all the values in three buttons I want the product of the values to be displayed in another button(fourth button).

My html code,

```
<label>S *</label>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" ng-click="Modal1()">{{cp.se}}</button>

                <label>O *</label>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" ng-click="Modal2()">{{fmea.oc}}</button>

                <label>D*</label>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" ng-click="Modal3()">{{fm.de}}</button>

                <label>RPN</label>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg">{{cp.se*fmea.oc*fm.de}}</button>
```

The above code displays the product value, but before selection of values in the three buttons, it shows a string, 'NaN'. I understand this is due to no initial value. But any idea how to overcome this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format your HTML so it does not display incorrect values, by using `ng-show` or `ng-if`:

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
   <span ng-if="(cp.se*fmea.oc*fm.de)">{{cp.se*fmea.oc*fm.de}}</span>
</button>
```

this way, the inner span will show only with **non-falsy** values.

Comment: accept the answer if you found it useful: don't leave the question as unaswered.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-init="cp.se = 0" or initalize the values in your controller

Comment: Thanks. Initializing works. previous solution is a lot easier one though.